# Azure Application Gateway WAFv2 across subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

What is best practise for Azure Application Gateway usage in the terms of reusibility for multiple customers?
Let´s say I have 4 subscriptions. Each subscription contains App Services inside VNET for different customer, some of this App Services should be public.
Is it a good idea to have one Application Gateway WAFv2 to route/secure traffic?
What are pros/cons here?

I am thinking how to save some money here.

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let me anwser my own question. Sharing of Application Gateway between multiple customers is not a good idea. Reasoning:

- Absolute separation of customer-specific resources from other customer-specific resources (Application Gateway must be inside same vnet as resources where traffic should be routed).
- One Application Gateway can have up-to 100 active listeners. It can handle huge traffic (v2 version) but for limited count of websites.